# Angular 5 with Bootstrap 4 not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular5

I created a new Angular 5 project. After that I followed instructions given on [Angular CLI GitHub page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap)
to use Bootstrap 4.0.0 with Angular 5.2.2. I use 'npm install bootstrap' to install bootstrap. but I get...

```
Unknown error from PostCSS plugin. Your current PostCSS version is 
6.0.15, but autoprefixer uses 5.2.18. Perhaps this is the source of 
the error below.
...
...
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?
{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-
loader/lib{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/bootstrap/
dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
...
...
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 25):

The following is an understandable consolidation of various tutorials that I have gone through. Please remember that it depends on the versions you are using.

#### 1. Install the angular cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

#### 2. Create an Angular project using angular cli

```
ng new my-awesome-project
```

#### 3. Install dependencies

Next, `cd` in your new project and install requiered dependencies:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

Whatch out about `popper.js`. This lib is used by Bootstrap. However, you have to precisely run `npm install popper.js --save` because `popper` is another js lib distributed by npm.

Here is my current configuration:

```
angular cli: 1.6.8
angular: ^5.2.0
bootstrap: ^4.0.0
jquery: ^3.3.1
popper.js: ^1.12.9
```

#### 4. Integrate the dependencies to your project

Now that you have all your dependencies, you'll have to "plug" bootstrap into your project.

Open `.angular-cli.json` file and update `script` section as follows:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

Finally, open `src\styles.css` and add:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

The last operation to be necessary when running angular project in production mode.

Comment: Thanks! Am using Angular 5 and bootstrap 4.0.0 beta.2.  I filled in my package.json and then ran npm install.  Your last 2 steps fixed the problems with bootstrap.

Comment: Great!! this answer works even today with Angular12 and Bootstrap5. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

`npm install bootstrap --save`

Open `.angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` file and update script section as shown in above answers.
Also add it to styles array:

`"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
]`

If this doesn't work, then open `src\styles.css` and add:

`@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

Answer (score 2):

Use `npm install bootstrap` to install Bootstrap 4.0.0. Take a look at [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) itself and its [npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap).

(The package for Bootstrap 3.3 is [`bootstrap@3`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/))

Comment: I can confirm that bootstrap 4 works well with angular yes when installed via npm/yarn.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I did install Bootstrap using nom install bootstrap. It installs bootstrap 4.0.0 but is does not work.

Answer (score 1):

you must downgrade to a beta version of bootstrap instead of using bootstrap@next
downgrade to bootstrap@4.0.2 beta version  available on npm

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am not using bootstrap@next. Using nom install bootstrap. It install bootstrap 4.0.0 version. Which is a release version. But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have,

```
1. Added the bootstrap.css file
2. Copied the fonts folder of bootstrap into the project
3. Added the file name in angularcli.json file
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has dependency on popper and jquery. It is always a good idea to install these modules along with bootstrap.

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4 jquery@version popper@version
```

using --save adds these dependencies in your package.json.

Then you can go to angular.json (Angular 6 and cli v6) or angular-cli.json (Angular 5 or below and cli v1.7) and paste the css of bootstrap in node modules under styles array. And add jquery, popper and bootstrap.js files under scripts.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add ngbootstrap by using the command

> ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics
> by adding schematics it will add necessory import to angular.json file.