# ng2-bootstrap-modal doesn't work after webpack compile

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, bootstrap-modal

I added to my angular project ng2-bootstrap-modal and I followed steps recomanded in this url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap-modal

Everiting works well until I publish it [the code was 'compiled' with webpack] into FAT env. From what I understand it cannot create dialog holder.

I dig deep into modal code and I found that the error is in " DialogService.prototype.createDialogHolder" from dialog.service.js

The original code from the component looks like:

```
DialogService.prototype.createDialogHolder = function () {
    var _this = this;
    var componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(dialog_holder_component_1.DialogHolderComponent);
    var componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
    var componentRootNode = componentRef.hostView.rootNodes[0];
    if (!this.container) {
        var componentRootViewContainer = this.applicationRef['_rootComponents'][0];
        this.container = componentRootViewContainer.hostView.rootNodes[0];
    }
    this.applicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
    componentRef.onDestroy(function () {
        _this.applicationRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
    });
    this.container.appendChild(componentRootNode);
    return componentRef.instance;
};
```

The code after webpack 'compilation' looks like:

```
t.prototype.createDialogHolder = function() {
        var t = this
          , e = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(u.DialogHolderComponent)
          , n = e.create(this.injector)
          , r = n.hostView.rootNodes[0];
        if (!this.container) {
            var o = this.applicationRef._rootComponents[0];
            this.container = o.hostView.rootNodes[0]
        }
        return this.applicationRef.attachView(n.hostView),
        n.onDestroy(function() {
            t.applicationRef.detachView(n.hostView)
        }),
        this.container.appendChild(r),
        n.instance
    }
```

And the error is in line:

```
var o = this.applicationRef._rootComponents[0];
```

Because _rootComponents is null.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?
Note: the code is 100% same as in the above link.

Upd: in app.module.ts I tried to import BootstrapModalModule with default container and also with specific container BootstrapModalModule.forRoot({ container: document.body })

Comment: It looks like `ng2` has been deprecated and replaced by `ngx`. See their [npm repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap). I believe you should log an issue in their [github repo](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)

Comment: Have you tried to import bootstrap in `src/styles.css`? Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593179/angular-5-with-bootstrap-4-not-working/49027017#49027017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer is valid for plain `bootstrap`. But since `ngx-bootstrap` (a.k.a `ng2-bootstrap`) is built on plain bootstrap, it still might be relevant.

I noticed that importing `bootstrap.css` in the `.angular-cli.json` file, as is recommended on the `ngx` worked in **dev** mode but did not work once compiled with `webpack`.

Importing bootstrap in the `src/styles.css` file, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593179/angular-5-with-bootstrap-4-not-working/49027017#49027017) did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had try it but I did not succeed. Probably I've made something wrong. I change it to ngx lib. Thanks @avi.elkharrat for your sugestions!

Answer (score 0):

We just need to add few lines to fix this issue for whole project, when you moved from angular 4 to 5+. Hope this helps if anyone still looking for a solution.

Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58201485/9312338